# How to handle Incremental Update in HDFS hadoop Map-Reduce

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, mapreduce, hdfs

I have structured base text files in HDF which have data like this (in file.txt):

```
OgId|^|ItemId|^|segmentId|^|Sequence|^|Action|!|

4295877341|^|136|^|4|^|1|^|I|!|
4295877346|^|136|^|4|^|1|^|I|!|
4295877341|^|138|^|2|^|1|^|I|!|
4295877341|^|141|^|4|^|1|^|I|!|
4295877341|^|143|^|2|^|1|^|I|!|
4295877341|^|145|^|14|^|1|^|I|!|
123456789|^|145|^|14|^|1|^|I|!|
```

The size of the file.txt is 30 GB.

I have incremental data file1.txt of size approx 2 GB coming up in the same format in HFDS like below:

```
OgId|^|ItemId|^|segmentId|^|Sequence|^|Action|!|

4295877341|^|213|^|4|^|1|^|I|!|
4295877341|^|213|^|4|^|1|^|I|!|
4295877341|^|215|^|2|^|1|^|I|!|
4295877341|^|141|^|4|^|1|^|I|!|
4295877341|^|143|^|2|^|1|^|I|!|
4295877343|^|149|^|14|^|2|^|I|!|
123456789|^|145|^|14|^|1|^|D|!|
```

Now i have to combine file.txt and file1.txt and create a final text file that has all unique records.

The key in both files are OrgId. If the same OrgId is found in the first file then I have to replace with the new OrgId and if not then then I have to insert the new OrgId.

The Final Output is  like this .

```
OgId|^|ItemId|^|segmentId|^|Sequence|^|Action|!|

4295877346|^|136|^|4|^|1|^|I|!|
4295877341|^|213|^|4|^|1|^|I|!|
4295877341|^|215|^|2|^|1|^|I|!|
4295877341|^|141|^|4|^|1|^|I|!|
4295877341|^|143|^|2|^|1|^|I|!|
4295877343|^|149|^|14|^|2|^|I|!|
```

How can i do it in mapreduce?

I am not going for the HIVE solution because I have so many distinct file like this, approx 10.000 and so I have to create 10.000 partitions in HIVE.

Any suggestion to use Spark for this use case ?

Comment: Why do you want in mapreduce? Can I suggest you answer in scala for Spark and Hadoop?

Comment: Yes please ...Some code would be great

Comment: I am guessing you have knowledge on Spark and Scala and dataFrame, is that right?

Comment: I didn't understand your line `.If same OrgId is found in the first file then i have to replace with the new OrgId and if not then then i have to insert new OrgId.` Can you clarify it?

Comment: Yes i have started learning that .Coming to my question basically i have to replace the records with new records if OrgId Matches if not then it is considered as new records so it will be appended .

Comment: What all have you tried till now?

Comment: @SanchitGrover I  was doing in HIVE but the no of partition for tables has increase so much .Also reduce side join but the size of the data is very huge so looking for some good suggestion .

Comment: @SUDARSHAN Is it that you merge everything from file2 but deletes records from file1 if id matches, is that so?

Comment: @RameshMaharjan yes exactly ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am suggesting you to program in `scala` for `spark`. If you program in `mapreduce`, it would be useful for only `hadoop` but programming in `scala` for `spark` would enable you process in `spark` as well as `hadoop`. `Spark` was initiated to handle the drawbacks in `mapreduce` model. You can find many resources on this topic. One of them is [this](https://www.usenix.org/system/files/conference/nsdi12/nsdi12-final138.pdf)

Regarding your problem, I am proposing you to use `dataframe`

First task would be to create `schema` for the dataframes.

```
val schema = StructType(Array(StructField("OgId", StringType),
  StructField("ItemId", StringType),
  StructField("segmentId", StringType),
  StructField("Sequence", StringType),
  StructField("Action", StringType)))
```

Next task is to read the two files and create dataframe using above schema

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val textRdd1 = sparkContext.textFile("input path to file1 in hdfs")
val rowRdd1 = textRdd1.map(line => Row.fromSeq(line.split("\\|\\^\\|", -1)))
var df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rowRdd1, schema)
df1 = df1.withColumn("Action", regexp_replace($"Action", "[|!|]", ""))

val textRdd2 = sparkContext.textFile("input path to file 2 in hdfs")
val rowRdd2 = textRdd2.map(line => Row.fromSeq(line.split("\\|\\^\\|", -1)))
var df2 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rowRdd2, schema)
df2 = df2.withColumn("Action", regexp_replace($"Action", "[|!|]", ""))
```

The output of `df1` is

```
+----------+------+---------+--------+------+
|OgId      |ItemId|segmentId|Sequence|Action|
+----------+------+---------+--------+------+
|4295877341|136   |4        |1       |I     |
|4295877346|136   |4        |1       |I     |
|4295877341|138   |2        |1       |I     |
|4295877341|141   |4        |1       |I     |
|4295877341|143   |2        |1       |I     |
|4295877341|145   |14       |1       |I     |
+----------+------+---------+--------+------+
```

And output of `df2` is

```
+----------+------+---------+--------+------+
|OgId      |ItemId|segmentId|Sequence|Action|
+----------+------+---------+--------+------+
|4295877341|213   |4        |1       |I     |
|4295877341|215   |2        |1       |I     |
|4295877341|141   |4        |1       |I     |
|4295877341|143   |2        |1       |I     |
|4295877343|149   |14       |2       |I     |
+----------+------+---------+--------+------+
```

Now according to your requirement you want to remove `rows` from `df1` if `OgId` matches with `df2` and append all of `df2` to `df1`. These requirements can be done as below

```
val tempdf = df2.select("OgId").withColumnRenamed("OgId", "OgId_1")

df1 = df1.join(tempdf, df1("OgId") === tempdf("OgId_1"), "left")
df1 = df1.filter("OgId_1 is null").drop("OgId_1")
df1 = df1.union(df2)
```

Final output is

```
+----------+------+---------+--------+------+
|OgId      |ItemId|segmentId|Sequence|Action|
+----------+------+---------+--------+------+
|4295877346|136   |4        |1       |I     |
|4295877341|213   |4        |1       |I     |
|4295877341|215   |2        |1       |I     |
|4295877341|141   |4        |1       |I     |
|4295877341|143   |2        |1       |I     |
|4295877343|149   |14       |2       |I     |
+----------+------+---------+--------+------+
```

This final result can be saved in `hdfs` as

```
df1.write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").save("output file path in hdfs")
```

I hope this is helpful

**Note : Make sure that you write the path of input and output locations correctly**

Comment: If you encounter any problem, please do let me know. :) And please upvote if you think the answer deserves one. ;) thanks

Comment: Hi Ramesh just one question ,If i will have incremental file that does not have same header as base file then also this solution will work ?And also my incremental files  are in order so if we do join then update order will be preserved ?

Comment: header names are defined with schema. So it doesn't matter if the header names are different. But the data should be in the same columnar format. And I didn't understand your second question.

Comment: Hi Ramesh dose this main the order also ?I mean the records that comes first will get updated first ?

Comment: yes it maintains the order but until join only. shuffling is done when joining. so the order after join is reordered.

Comment: So in my case this solution might now work .Because i update/insert/delete in same order as files arrives .First record in a files has to be updated first .

Comment: you can assign serial number column and sort with that column before you write to file. This will solve the issue you are having

Comment: Hi Ramesh ..I have done the same thing but when saving the Dataframe output to text file my job is getting failed ..Any idea..here is the question link ..Please have a look ..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46190580/saveastextfile-hangs-in-spark-java-io-ioexception-connection-reset-by-peer-in-d

Comment: Hi Ramesh Can you please tell me why df1.write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").save("output file path in hdfs") This takes very long time ?

Comment: it depends on how big is your data and how many partitions are you using. try to remove coalesce and it should be fast .

Comment: I have removed that ..The data set i have is 100 gb and 20 gb ..It takes very very long time to complete ..Where as in HIVE it takes 13 minutes ..

Comment: did you look at the logs . logs of hadoop and logs of spark? if there are anything suspicious. like memory issue or something like that

Comment: Yes but i have not seen any issue related to memory ...My only concern is that is runs very slow ...

Comment: did you try writing to parquet file without converting to rdd.? See if that too  gets slow.

Comment: Yes still slower but in csv format it is faster ..I am using AWS r4X16 machine .In csv format it takes 8 minutes in perquet it takes 10 minutes ..Can this be more optimized ?

Comment: 8 min is already faster for 100gb file. how much faster do you need?

Comment: I am able to do this in Hive in less than 13 minutes so i was thinking if spark can do this within 5 minutes or not ..Just a quick question if i have enough memory what can i increase i.e executor.memory or core to make my spark run much much faster ...?

Comment: play with them :) I guess you can do that. I suggest you to increase the executor cores :)

Comment: Ramesh just one quick question if i have Action type Delete in df2 can we remove row from df1 having same orgId for the Delete Action tag?

Comment: you will have to join them both . Without joining its a bit tricky :)

Comment: by the way did you get solved the executor cores one?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154961/discussion-between-sudarshan-and-ramesh-maharjan).