# saveAsTextFile hangs in spark java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer in Data frame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hadoop-yarn, apache-spark-dataset

I am running an application in spark which do the simple diff between two data frame .
I execute as jar file in my cluster environment .
My cluster environment is 94 node cluster.
There are two data set 2 GB and 4 GB which mapped to data frame .

My job is working fine for the very small size files ...

I personal think `saveAsTextFile` takes more time in my application 
Below my cluster connfig details

```
Total Vmem allocated for Containers     394.80 GB
Total Vmem allocated for Containers     394.80 GB
Total VCores allocated for Containers   36
```

This is how i run my spark job

```
spark-submit --queue root.queue --deploy-mode client --master yarn SparkApplication-SQL-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

Here is my code .

```
object TestDiff {

   def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("WordCount"); 

    conf.set("spark.executor.memory", "32g")
    conf.set("spark.driver.memory", "32g")
    conf.set("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "4g")

    val sc = new SparkContext(conf); //Creating spark context
    val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
    import sqlContext.implicits._

    import org.apache.spark.{ SparkConf, SparkContext }
    import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
    import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{ StructType, StructField, StringType, DoubleType, IntegerType }
    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf

     val schema = StructType(Array(
      StructField("filler1", StringType),
      StructField("dunsnumber", StringType),
      StructField("transactionalindicator", StringType)))

    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

    val textRdd1 = sc.textFile("/home/cloudera/TRF/PCFP/INCR")

    val rowRdd1 = textRdd1.map(line => Row.fromSeq(line.split("\\|", -1)))
    var df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rowRdd1, schema)

    val textRdd2 = sc.textFile("/home/cloudera/TRF/PCFP/MAIN")

    val rowRdd2 = textRdd2.map(line => Row.fromSeq(line.split("\\|", -1)))
    var df2 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rowRdd2, schema)

    //Finding the diff between two if any of the columns has changed 
    val diffAnyColumnDF = df1.except(df2)
    diffAnyColumnDF.rdd.coalesce(1).saveAsTextFile("Diffoutput") 
}
}
```

It takes more than 30 minutes and then it fails  .

with below exception

Here is the logs

```
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [10 seconds]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:219)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:223)
    at scala.concurrent.Await$$anonfun$result$1.apply(package.scala:107)
    at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$DefaultBlockContext$.blockOn(BlockContext.scala:53)
    at scala.concurrent.Await$.result(package.scala:107)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:75)
    ... 14 more
17/09/15 11:55:01 WARN netty.NettyRpcEnv: Ignored message: HeartbeatResponse(false)
17/09/15 11:56:19 WARN netty.NettyRpcEndpointRef: Error sending message [message = Heartbeat(1,[Lscala.Tuple2;@7fe57079,BlockManagerId(1, c755kds.int.int.com, 33507))] in 1 attempts
org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeoutException: Futures timed out after [10 seconds]. This timeout is controlled by spark.executor.heartbeatInterval
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.org$apache$spark$rpc$RpcTimeout$$createRpcTimeoutException(RpcTimeout.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:59)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:33)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEndpointRef.askWithRetry(RpcEndpointRef.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$reportHeartBeat(Executor.scala:491)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(Executor.scala:520)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Executor.scala:520)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Executor.scala:520)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1818)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anon$1.run(Executor.scala:520)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [10 seconds]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:219)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:223)
    at scala.concurrent.Await$$anonfun$result$1.apply(package.scala:107)
    at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$DefaultBlockContext$.blockOn(BlockContext.scala:53)
    at scala.concurrent.Await$.result(package.scala:107)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:75)
    ... 14 more
17/09/15 11:56:19 WARN netty.NettyRpcEnv: Ignored message: HeartbeatResponse(false)
```

Please suggest how to tune my spark job ?

I just changed executor memory and it job got succeeded but it is very very slow  .

```
conf.set("spark.executor.memory", "64g")
```

But job is very slow ...It takes around 15 minutes to complete ..

And job has taken 15 minutes to complete .

Attaching DAG Visualization

[image]

After increasing the time out conf getting below error ..

```
 executor 5): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 5 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Executor heartbeat timed out after 175200 ms
```

Comment: Are u using yarn mode?

Comment: Also can you paste your optimizers execution plan, task execution times and the DAG. Further whats is ur executor configs? Number, memory, cores.

Comment: Yes i am using yarn mode like this  --deploy-mode client --master yarn

Comment: @datmannz my job runs for more than 30 minutes and then it fails ...

Comment: try conf.set("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "10g") and repartition(10) instead of coalesce

Comment: @morfious902002 still same error...

Comment: @morfious902002 updated the logs with the latest one ..The job is failing now  ..

Comment: conf.set("spark.executor.heartbeatInterval","120s") should help with the error. Try it out.

Comment: @morfious902002 no luck ... executor 5): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 5 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Executor heartbeat timed out after 175200 ms

Comment: conf.set("spark.network.timeout","360s")
conf.set("spark.executor.heartbeatInterval","240s")

Answer (score 1):

I think your single partitiond file size is big. it takes long time to stream the data over the TCP channel and the connection can not be made alive for a long time and gets reset.

Can you coalesce to a higher number of partitions?

Comment: Sure i will try with 500 like diffAnyColumnDF.rdd.coalesce(500, shuffle = true).saveAsTextFile("Diffoutput")

Comment: Same result job failed again

Comment: Is the error the same? Is your name node up and data nodes up? Can you paste the full log generated?

Comment: Of particular interest is the line ""17/09/13 06:44:44 ERROR cluster.YarnScheduler: Lost executor 1 on a0123456.int.intgroup.com: Executor heartbeat timed out after 137337 ms."" It clearly says that the app master isnt able to  get the hearbeat from one of d executor. Now, typically either the network or your node need to be monitored for the cause. Makes sense?

Comment: Yes it is the same error and my node are up ..Other map reduce job is getting passed ..In the UP i can see that in the saveAsTextFile phase job  taking very long time

Comment: I think so but i am very new to spark application so i have rasied one ticket for the internal team also ..Will update you on that soon..

Comment: In the meanwhile can you also try the following:
1. diffAnyColumnDF.rdd.coalesce(10, shuffle = true).saveAsTextFile("Diffoutput")

2. diffAnyColumnDF.rdd.coalesce(100).saveAsTextFile("Diffoutput")